# Querying firebase with filtering data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have the Json in following format on firebase:

```
          {
           "30000000549656652" : {
            "cast" : [ {
              "src" : "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images",
              "title" : "Hilary Duff (Samantha \"Sam\" Montgomery)"
            }],
            "channel_name" : "HBO",
            "desc" : "After her .....",
            "extras" : {
              "initial" : "July 10, 2004 (Hollywood)",
              "director" : "Mark Rosman",
              "screenplay" : "Leigh Dunlap"  
            },
            "genre" : "Thriller",
            "lang" : "English",
            "movie" : 1,
            "prog_id" : 30000000549656652,
            "prog_img" : "http://images."
    "ratings" : {
              "IMDb" : "5.9/10",
              "Metacritic" : "25%",
              "Rotten Tomatoes" : "11%"
            },
            "start" : 201607141800,
            "stop" : 201607141700,
            "title" : "Thrill A Cinderella Story",
            "year" : "2004"
          },
    .....

}
```

I want to do the following in activity on my android app-
Query the node in which these JSON exist, then filter them such that i get all the results which have movies of one specific genre(e.g., Thriller) and the year is within five yrs less or five yrs more of the one i would pass in the query.
Like i would want to query to get all thriller movies whose "year" are between 2000 and 2009.
Can someone please help me to build such query for a json like this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem?

Comment: no solution, complex queries cannot be done in firebase easily